# Destroy gameobject in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

I want the enemy to be destroyed when the player touches the heart. what's wrong with my code?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public float speed;
    void Update()
    {

        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.transform.position, 
speed * Time.deltaTime);

   
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (player.gameObject.CompareTag("haret"))
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: you wrote **haret** in your `CompareTg("haret")` function. maybe problem is this typo. Should it be heart

Comment: Getting any errors? In general using `transform.position` might be breaking the physics and collision detection ..

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided an error code or anything so I don't have much to go off of ;-;

make sure the tag in the code is the same as the code in the project and put the tag on the heart.

make sure that the player gameobject has been assigned to the enemy.

make sure that the player and the heart both have a 2d collider not set to is trigger

Answer (score 0):

Check your tag spelling. You have a spelling mistake there.

Answer (score 0):

Without an error it is hard to figure out what the problem is. From the looks of it you might have misspelled `gameObject.CompareTag("haret")` where it should be `gameObject.CompareTag("heart")` instead.

Also make sure that the script is assigned to the enemy, that you have assigned the `player` gameObject in the inspector and that you have set the collider of the heart gameObject to isTrigger in the inspector.